# Is there a way to tell how many on-going threads in the master process from a DLL?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

The scenario is here:

If a program is executed, at runtime assume it will link to some DLL files, the (master) program/process may or may not create multi-threading function-calls to the functions in DLLs.

Then is there a way that the DLL,  of cause besides parameter-passing, can tell whether the master process, who calls the functions within the DLL at runtime,  is in a single or multi-thread manner (For instance, by Open MP)?

Comment: What platform/framework you are using?

Comment: @rkosegi Mainly for windows, but sometimes for RHEL 6.0+, programming mostly with Intel MPI, OpenMP and Pthreads

Comment: Your DllMain() entrypoint will be called with the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH reason when the main process creates a new thread.  This is unlikely to be useful, but you did too little to explain why you need this.

Answer (score 1):

You can check and compare the current thread ID to detect calls from different threads. You could also implement a DLLMain() function that gets called for every started and terminated thread. I'm pretty sure you can also retrieve a handle to the current process and enumerate the threads running in it. Only the first version will actually tell you if your code is run from different threads though, I think that e.g. WinSock will create a thread for you, even though your program is single-threaded otherwise.

BTW: Consider adding win32api tag and removing C++ tag.

Comment: The Toolhelp api (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686832(v=vs.85).aspx) will let you take a snapshot of a process and enumerate the threads... DLLMain() will get notifications of thread attach and detach unless something in the process disables it for that dll using DisableThreadLibraryCalls(). The only way to know if you're being called from a single thread is to take the thread id (GetCurrentThreadId()) of the calling thread at each function entry point into  the dll and compare with the previously stored result. The compare needs to be done in a thread safe manner.